# Fetch JSON data, wikimedia

Tags: php, json, mediawiki, wikipedia-api

**Problem**

I have this JSON content which I got from wikimedia API in JSON format. I want to extract the data under **[*]** this. Although I don't know prior to making call the page id so I can't use the pageid in the middle. Also I don't how to pass **astrics ( * )**. I have used following to code to fetch the data but getting an error.

I'll really appreciate any help or guidance.

**Code**

```
$api_data->query->pages->revisions[0]->['*'];
```

**JSON**

```
stdClass Object
(
    [batchcomplete] => 
    [query] => stdClass Object
        (
            [pages] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [27000] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [pageid] => 27000
                            [ns] => 0
                            [title] => Patna
                            [revisions] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [contentformat] => text/x-wiki
                                            [contentmodel] => wikitext
                                            [*] => ==Understand==
The ancient name of Patna was 'Pataliputra' and it was the capital of the Maurya and Gupta empires. Located at the site where Patna is today, the ancient city of Patliputra, with a glorious period of history spanning a thousand years (500BC-400AD), saw the rise and fall of India's first major kingdoms.

Lying along the banks of the Ganges River, Patna is surrounded by important religious centers for the Buddhists, Sikhs and Jains. This city has been home to two great religions, Buddhism and Jainism, and myriad dynasties from ancient to modern times.
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: `$api_data->query->pages->revisions[0]->{'*'};`

Comment: thanks that helped !!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the property name into brackets as Chay22 proposed:

```
$data->first = 'hello';
$data->{'*'} = 'world';

var_dump($data);

// Like this
echo $data->{'*'};
echo PHP_EOL;

// or like this
$varname = '*';

echo $data->{$varname};
echo PHP_EOL;
```